# Serverless Framework - Implement and override existing Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

So im trying to implement serverless framework on an existing AWS lambda function that was initially created manually (So through the AWS CLI) and leverage the already existing resources around it (Those being an already created IAM role, log-group and to use the existing ALB its already getting triggered from). However, I'm struggling to implement it because every direction I turn im running into blockers with errors like the one below.

```
"Resource of type 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup' with identifier '{"/properties/LogGroupName":"/aws/lambda/my-function"}' already exists." (RequestToken: xxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
```

This is my current serverless.yml template:

```
service: my-function-service
frameworkVersion: ^3.3.0

custom:
  functionName: my-function

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  iam:
    role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/an_existing_lambda_role

package:
  patterns:
    - "!.vs"
    - "!.ide"
    - "!.deploy"
    - "!.nyc_output"
    - "!.serverless"
    - "!coverage"
    - "!node_modules"
    - "!schemas"
    - "!src"
    - "!test"
    - "!.eslintrc.json"
    - "!.gitignore"
    - "!.gitlab-ci.yml"
    - "!.mocharc.js"
    - "!.nycrc.json"
    - "!gulpfile.js"
    - "!*.ts"
    - "!LICENSE"
    - "!package-lock.json"
    - "!package.json"
    - "!README.md"
    - "!serverless.yml"
    - "!*.zip"
    - "!sonar-project.properties"
    - "!tsconfig.json"
    - "!webpack.config.js"
    - "dist/**"
    - "schemas/**"
    - "README.md"

functions:
  my-function:
    handler: index.handler
    description: A lambda for doing xyz
    runtime: nodejs18.x
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - alb:
          listenerArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:XXXXXX:listener/app/a-alb/xxxxx/xxxx
          priority: 1
          conditions:
            path: /


resources:
  Resources:
    MyFunctionLogGroup:
      Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
      DeletionPolicy: "Retain"
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: /aws/lambda/${self:custom.functionName}
```

So firstly im wondering if this is even possible ? And secondly, what am I doing wrong, how am i meant to specify this configuration ?

Hoping someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On deployment of a serverless application it creates/updates a cloudformation stack on AWS. And a deployment process can only create/delete/update resources from that cloudformation stack. I don't know how big your application is, but if possible, I'd suggest to remove the existing resources and migrate them into your serverless project, because everything else seems rather cumbersome and error-prone to me ...

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for replying! So the application is small, just a simple lambda that gets triggered from an ALB event and does some DB manipulation. The problem with removing, is those resources are already being used within a production environment. So I'm effectively looking to "override" the existing application with a  serverless deployment to register these resources with cloud-formation and then update some config properties